# Mixed section numbering accross subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I would like to change from section numbering 4.3.1 to 4.3.A, and then 4.4.1 to 4.4.B, 4.4.C and then also keep it counting into the next section. such that there is a consistent count from A - Z. I couldn't find a solution so far, any thoughts?

[image]

To clarify: I want them to have the numbering of the respective subsection but the subsubsection should count without resetting (I am trying to number Exeriments across different sections)

Comment: Are *all* `\subsubsection`s to be numbered this way? Or just for Chapter 4? What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You already ask this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386803/124842). It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: This would just be needed for this chapter 4 and I am using \documentclass[bibtotoc,liststotoc]{scrbook}.

Comment: @Werner Do you think this is possible? Just can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps:

1. Redefine the way `\thesubsection` is printed:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
   ```

   This will ensure the subsections are enumerated using A, B, C, ...
2. Skip the first subsection number for section 4.4 using

   ```
   \stepcounter{subsection}
   ```
3. Restore the original `\thesubsection` formatting:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
   ```

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{3}% Just for this example

\chapter{Experiments and Results}

\section{Datasets}

\section{Optimization}

\section{High-level model}

% Change formatting of subsection counter representation
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}

\subsection{A: Deep Gaze II}

\section{Lower-level models}

% Skip typical first subsection numbering
\stepcounter{subsection}

\subsection{B: ICF}

\subsection{C: Parameterized Gabor}

\subsection{D: ICF + Parameterized Gabor}

\subsection{E: Itti \& Koch}

\subsection{F: I\& K + ICF}

% Restore typical subsection numbering/representation (if needed)
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\section{Summary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! I wanted to include a subsubsection e.g. 4.4.E.1 which didn't work, my command: \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}.\thesubsubsection} ?

Comment: Do subsubsections in your document have display numbers already?